# Generator Reading Log File While Name Changes Python

Tags: python, generator, filenames, filenotfoundexception

The goal is to read a log file in real time line by line (standard generator stuff) but the catch is, the file name changes at various intervals. The name change can't be helped (application dictated appended with a time string) and the name is changed when the log file size reaches ~2MB (guesstimate).

My approach was to create a file getter function that got the file (or new file) and then passed that to the generator. I thought that when the file changed names I would get a 'File not found' error, but what my test showed, is that the file name change is prevented entirely as 'another program is using this file'. The name change must be allowed, and this reader code cannot interfere with the application logging process at all.

```
import os
import time
import fnmatch

directory = '\\foo\\'

def fileGenerator(logFile):
     """ Run a line generator """
     logFile.seek(0,2)
     while True:
         line = logFile.readline()
         if not line:
             time.sleep(0.1)
             continue
         yield line

def fileGetter():
     """ Get the Logging File """
     matchedFiles = []
     for afile in os.listdir(directory):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(afile,'amc_*.txt'):
            matchedFiles.append(afile)
     if len(matchedFiles)==1:
        #There was exactly one matching file found send it to the generator
        return os.path.join(directory,matchedFiles[0])
    else:
        #There either wasn't a file found or many matching
        #Error out and stop process... critical error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filePath = fileGetter()
    try:
        logFile = open(filePath,"r")
    except Exception as e:
        #Catch the file not found and go back to the file path getter
        #Send the file back to the generator
        print e
    if logFile:
        loglines = fileGenerator(logFile)
        for line in loglines:
            #handle the line
            print line,
```

Comment: How "real-time" does your application need to be? Is it OK to check the file every few seconds? Every minute? When the file changes names, does its contents remain the same?

Comment: If this is Windows (which is where this sort of sharing violation is most likely) and it were lower level, I'd say to take a look at using [opportunistic locking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/15/10410965.aspx). It _might_ be possible to do this using [`win32file.DeviceIoControl`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32file__DeviceIoControl_meth.html) and other `win32file` APIs, but it would be ugly in Python.

Comment: Real time enough to catch the data. Top speed might be something ~2MB every 10 min... but the caught data isn't actually used in real time, so the only speed needed is for catching the data. When the file changes all old data is dumped, the file starts blank and begins to fill again (stupid logging method IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't hold the file open while waiting for new content to be written to it, I suggest saving the file position you were last at and closing the file before you sleep, and then reopening the file and seeking to that point afterwards. You could also investigate filesystem notification systems if you care about spotting file additions or renames immediately.

```
def log_reader():
    filename = "does_not_exist"
    filepos = 0

    while True:
        try:
            file = open(filename)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            filename = fileGetter()
            # if renamed files start empty, set filepos to zero here!
            continue

        file.seek(filepos)

        while True:
            line = file.readline()
            if not line:
                filepos = file.tell()
                file.close()
                sleep(0.1) # you may want to test different sleep lengths to avoid FS thrash
                break
            yield line
```

The opening and closing of the file may stress out your filesystem if you do it too much, so I'd suggest sleeping longer than your previous code did (but you may want to test to see how well your OS handles it if you care about how responsive your log reader is).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In your example, it still could be the case that I go to read, the application goes to change the name, and the application can't because the file is being used by the reader?

Comment: @AdrianBoeh: I suspect that yes, the other application could still have problems, but the odds of it happening will be vastly less, since this code only keep the file open while it is being read (not while waiting for new entries). I suppose there are ways you could further modify it to avoid opening the file as often, such as checking the file metadata to see if the length has changed rather than just trying to read another line, but I'd test to see if the issue is a real one first.